# how to use a returned value from javascript function inside input field?

Tags: javascript, php, html, select

Since I could not explain the question posted sometime earlier, Here is a another try. All i want is to have the value of a current option that is selected, so that i can echo that value inside the input field's value.

#### JavaScript

```
function id() {
    var sel = document.getElementById("cate");
    // to get the value of the selected option
    var selectedid = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    return selectedid;
}
```

#### PHP

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <select name="cate">
    <?php 
        $que1 = "SELECT * FROM category";
        $res1 = mysql_query($que1);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res1)) {    
            $cat_id_db = $row['cat_id'];                 
            $cat_db = $row['cat_name'];                  
    ?>

        <option value="<?php echo $cat_id_db; ?>" >
            <?php echo $cat_db;?>
        </option>

    <? } ?>
    </select>

    <p><label class="field">Category ID:</label></p>

    //HERE!
    <input type="text" name="cat_id"  value="<?php echo $cat_id_db; ?>" class="textbox-300" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\. ]+" title="Please enter your Item Price">
</form>
```

`//HERE!`: this is the place where i want to use the value of the current/selected option instead of the php code written.

Comment: you haven't explained what you want to do with the value, or how the js function is called. Explain in detail what you are trying to do

Comment: @depperm like i said, i want the returned value (from the option) to be echoed inside the input field's value. Im not sure about the js function, like from where could i call it from and how to store the value returned from it, so i could echo it inside the input field's value type.

Comment: When you say "the returned value (from the option)", do you mean the value of the select after the user has interacted with it, or just when the page loads?

Comment: @Serlite when the page opens for the first time, the current value and as the user interacts with it, the "interacted" value!

Comment: Removed Mysql tag: the question is not about the Mysql DB. Improved code formatting and indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how http process works. Php runs on the server, js in the browser(mostly). If all you want to do is set the inputs value, the do it all with javascript:

```
<form action = "" method = "POST">

    <select name="cate" onchange="changeInput(this.value);">
        <?php //your php code here ?>
    </select>

    <p><label class = "field">Category ID:</label></p>
    <input type = "text" name = "cat_id" id="cat_id" value = "change select to see me change" class = "textbox-300" pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9\. ]+"  title = "Please enter your Item Price">
</form>

<script>
    var changeInput = function (val){
        var input = document.getElementById("cat_id");
        input.value = val;
    }
</script>
```

live example: https://jsfiddle.net/nr8c8j8L/

Comment: there is something that i want to tell you, I FREAKING LOVE YOU!

Comment: @MuneerKhan Ha ha, no problem, glad i could help you

Comment: @MuneerKhan Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow - don't forget that once a question has been successfully answered, you should click the checkmark next to the answer that solved your question. This way, it's easier for us to keep track of which questions still need answering.

Comment: @Serlite, tried doing that but i dont have enough reputation. will do that soon as i can! :)

Comment: @MuneerKhan All right! But just to make sure we're on the same page, I mean the grey checkmark, not the grey up arrow. There should be no minimum reputation requirement for the checkmark. =P

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to set element's id. Not "name"

```
<select name="cate" id=cate>
```

Second, why you have to re-write selected item into input element?
in server side, you can get  element's value using $_POST['cate']

Comment: Thankyou for you reply, Please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31723050/how-to-use-the-current-value-of-a-select-option-inside-input-field you will know what I am trying to do. The input field Category ID is actually a Primary key in its table and a Foreign key in the current form where I trying to access it.